# How to set headerMode on some routes but not others. (React Navigation)

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

With [React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/) Is it possible to define certain routes with a headerMode and others without?

The majority of my pages don't use the header and I found how to turn it off globally.

```js
export const App = StackNavigator({
  PhotoView: {
    screen: Photos
  },
  ListView: {
    screen: List
  }
}, {
  headerMode: 'none'
});
```

But if I wanted to show the header on `ListView` for example, how would I do that?

I've tried several approaches from the docs but no luck.

Answer (score 12):

You can wrap your app navigator in a root navigator, set `navigationOptions.header` to `null` to hide all wrapped navigators header,  then set `navigationOptions.headerTitle` on screen that you want to display header.

This answer is based from react-navigation version v1.0.0-beta.9

```js
const App = StackNavigator({
  PhotoView: {
    screen: Photos,
  },
  ListView: {
    screen: List,
    navigationOptions: {
      headerTitle: 'ListView',
    },
  }
});

export const Root = StackNavigator({
  Root: { 
    screen: App,
    navigationOptions: {
      header: null,
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. It did work but there is a space where the header would've been. Imagine your phone in camera mode but the picture is pushed down about 40px.

Comment: You can set your  `PhotoView` `navigationOptions.headerTitle` to `null`  to remove the space

Comment: The solution and comment @alpha provided is close. Setting headerTitle to null for `PhotoView` will hide the title, but not the height of the bar...

What you need to do is set `navigationOptions.headerStyle` for `PhotoView` to { display: 'none' } - this achieves the desired no-header look for `PhotoView`, and allows the header to display for `ListView`

Answer (score 8):

You can hide the navigator header in the component of the *screen* attribute with:

```js
static navigationOptions = {
    header: null
};
```

Comment: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-navigator.html#header it appears to be in the docs now